# Python Pickle Memory Issue

Tags: python, memory, pickle, dump

First of all thank you in advance!

So I'm trying to Pickle.dump a large dictionary object containing patent citation information.

I'm receiving the not-so-verbose error 'MemoryError'.

I presume this is because the file is too big for Pickle to dump into memory. Has anyone got any suggestions of how I could get around this issue / good alternatives for large file-size memory storage.

To dump I'm simply using the code:

```
def pickleDumpCd():
with open("./PickleDumpCd","wb")as cdFP:
    pickle.dump(createSameTSVDateDict("uspatentcitation.tsv"),cdFP)
```

Being dumped is a dictionary created from a TSV (code below):

```
def createSameTSVDateDict(path):
citationDateDict = defaultdict()
with open(path) as citTSV:
    print("Creating Same TSV Date Dict")
    header = 0
    for line in csv.reader(citTSV, dialect="excel-tab"):
        if header > 0 and line[1] not in citationDateDict:
            citationDateDict[line[1]] = [(line[3],line[2])]
        elif header > 0 and line[2] in citationDateDict:
            citationDateDict[line[1]].append((line[3],line[2]))
        header += 1
return citationDateDict
```

This issue has been plaguing me for a while, so any thoughts / suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks,
Louis

Comment: normally, MemoryError does not occur for "file too big", but because Python cannot allocate enough memory (RAM). Do you use Python 32bit or 64bit? If 32, try switching to 64bit version.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) win32 - I doubt this is the issue, but thanks for the swift response!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem which I solved by installing 64 bit version of python. If the data you are trying to pickle is not too large this might solve your problem.

Comment: I'm currently running 64 bit Python - but thanks for the response